# PowerShell search for files based on their size

Tags: powershell

Windows search allows for searching files by their size by entering a search query such as `size:gigantic` or `size:large`.

I tried using that with `Get-ChildItem`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Filter "size:large" -Recurse
```

However this seems to treat it as a location and throws this error:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Is there any way to get PowerShell to search my disk for files of those size buckets as defined by Windows Search instead of implemeting the whole thing myself? And if not PowerShell, can Batch do this? Or is it possible to call a Windows API for Windows Search (if there's one) from PowerShell to accomplish this?

Comment: *"instead of implemeting the whole thing myself"* - in PowerShell alone most probably not. For file searches you might want to take a look at [Voidtools Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/), it's better than Windows Search by leaps and bounds and it features a command line interface.

Comment: the `-Filter` parameter is handled by the OS filesystem. the `Size:` stuff is provided by the windows search code. PoSh has no direct link to the WinSearch stuff that i know of. you will have to code that yourself, find it pre-done, or dig up a way to use the WinSearch code. the last will likely need c# to call system resources [or possible dotnet stuff].

Comment: "implemeting the whole thing myself" would be as simple as `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Length -ge $minLength -and $_.Length -le $maxLength }` (passing `-File` to `Get-ChildItem` would be good, too, and you may want `-Force` as well).  Are you looking specifically for some kind of shorthand that can be typed quickly in an interactive session, or do you need something that's consistent with however Explorer defines those size groups (as I recall, even "gigantic" was never all that...gigantic), or...?

Answer (score 0):

You can mimic the size buckets using the `ValidateSet` [parameter attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters#validateset-attribute) in a function like this:

```
function Search-FileBySize {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [ValidateSet(
            'Empty (0KB)', 'Tiny (0KB-16KB)', 
            'Small (16KB-1MB)', 'Medium (1MB-128MB)', 
            'Large (128MB-1GB)', 'Huge (1GB-4GB)', 'Gigantic (>4GB)'
        )]
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$size
    );

    $range = $size -replace '^\w+\s+\(([^()]+)\)$', '$1' -split '-' |
             foreach { 
                Invoke-Expression $_.ToString().Replace('>', ''); 
             }

    $condition = if ($range -is [array]) {
        { $args[0] -ge $range[0] -and $args[0] -le $range[1] };
    } else {
        if ($range -gt 0) { { $args[0] -gt $range }; } 
        else { { $args[0] -eq $range }; }
    }

    Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\' `
                  -Recurse -File `
                  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
    where { & $condition $_.Length; }
}
```

PowerShell ISE and other code editors will pick up valid parameter values from `ValidateSet`. E.g.:

```
$files = Search-FileBySize -size 'Large (128MB-1GB)';
# Intellisense gives you this    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Hard-coded the `Get-ChildItem` path to keep the example short. If you find the function helpful, should probably add a path parameter with validation.

Comment: This is a great tip, I was not aware of this parameter attribute, thanks! However I am looking to use the same sets as Windows uses and don't want to duplicate them in my code, so I will look for a way to query them from Windows instead.